# pipeline to decode and encode my mpeg4 video passing through some filter

Tags: gstreamer

I use the following pipeline to play my video on screen

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=01_189_libxvid_1920x1080_6M.mp4 ! 
qtdemux ! mpeg4videoparse ! omxmpeg4videodec ! videobalance brightness=100 ! 
video/x-raw,format=BGRA ! waylandsink --gst-debug=*:2
```

but now instead of directly playing I want to encode it and save it in some folder. Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this (example with h264 codec):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e --gst-debug=3 \
filesrc location="/path/input/sample_in.mp4" \
! qtdemux \
! mpeg4videoparse \
! omxmpeg4videodec \
! queue \
! x264enc \
! qtmux \
! filesink location="/path/output/sample_out.mp4"
```